# passing clientID to javascript and extracting a value, clarification

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, clientid

Forgive the noob question, but I'm trying to get my head wrapped around this. I have some controls that are inside of an  in a listview that are used to submit some information. I'm running a test pattern here to do this, but I'm getting object undefined errors. All of the articles I've seen about this are kind of vague. In this example, I'm trying to pass the id of a textbox, then pull the value from that in javascript. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ClientIDS(id) {
                var info = document.getElementById(id).value;
                alert(info);
                return false;
            }
        </script>
        <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lsvTest">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTextBox" />
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' OnClientClick="ClientIDS('<%=txtTextBox.ClientID %>')" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>

    </form>
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the rendered `View Source` to see the `input type="submit"` markup to make sure it's what you'd expect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you are want to doing using `jquery` than try this

just replace in button `onclientclick` with this one

```
   OnClientClick="ClientIDS(this);"
```

and than find your previous `input text` in to `asp:listview`

```
function ClientIDS(obj) {

   var txt = $(obj).prevAll('input[id*="txtTextBox"]:first');
   alert($(txt).val());

   return false;
}
```

Comment: brilliant. i was able to test this with the outer listview with no problems. I will get to trying it with the nested list soon. Thanks!

Comment: i can already see this being a bit more involved. Is there a way to say, go up 4 levels then look at ALL children of that to find the correct control in this same fashion? The reason that I ask is because The button is going to be contained in a div which is in div, which is in a div, etc, and not all controls that I need values for are going to be in the same div.

Comment: nevermind, i guess just find the parent of the whole block and use .find() instead of prevall

Comment: got it. used $(this).closest('.ParentTag').find('selector').val();

Comment: @sinaesthetic.sorry i have seen your response late.but glad to solve your problem. cheer!!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't have inline code in a property for a server control.

Generally I would do this in the codefile.

```
    for (int j = 0; j < this.lsvTest.Items.Count; j++)
    {
        var btnSubmit = (Button)this.lsvTest.Items[j].FindControl("btnSubmit");
        var txtTextBox = (TextBox)this.lsvTest.Items[j].FindControl("txtTextBox");
        btnSubmit.Attributes["onclick"] = string.Format("ClientIDS('{0}')", txtTextBox.ClientID);
    }
```

Comment: I think the problem with this is that in the final product, I'm going to end up having a listview nested inside of the outer listview's ItemTemplate. And as such, the inner list isn't exposed in the codefile. Not sure how that works

Comment: same idea, loop through the outer listview items and do findcontrol to get the inner listview. then loop the inner listview items.

Answer (score 1):

### Java Script Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ClientIDS(Btnid) {
        var textBoxID = Btnid.id.replace('btnSubmit', 'txtTextBox');
        var info = document.getElementById(textBoxID).value;
        alert(info);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

---

### HTML Code

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lsvTest">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTextBox" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' OnClientClick="ClientIDS(this)" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you're using javascript to do what you're jQuery library should be doing.

For example:

```
var info = document.getElementById(id).value;
//  is easier as
var info = $("#"+id).val();
```

Secondly, it's been awhile, but i dont think you can put your asp script text in the form like that

Comment: if you're gonna use straight js, then why include jQuery lib?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ItemDataBound event for the repeater to make this. See the following code

```
protected void lsvTest_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    string txtbox = e.Item.FindControl("txtTextBox").ClientID;
    Button btn = e.Item.FindControl("btnSubmit") as Button;
    btn.OnClientClick = string.Format("ClientIDS('{0}')", txtbox);
}
```

Comment: you are right txtbox  is a string equal txtTextBox's clientID which is defined in the first line